# Prove that $\mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(A_k)$ when the sets $A_i$ are almost disjoint.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure-space. Let $A_1, A_2, \dots \in \mathcal{A}$ and assume that $\mu(A_i \cap A_j)=0$ for $i \ne j$. Prove that $\mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(A_k).$

For the finite case I was able to prove this with noting that $A_1 \cup A_2 = (A_1 \setminus A_2) \cup(A_2 \setminus A_1) \cup(A_1 \cap A_2)$ and then using the finite additivity of $\mu$, but I cannot get this with countable many sets. Is there a set identity that I'm not familiar with where I could express $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ as I did for the finite case or should I even be considering this in the first place?

Comment: Do you know inclusion-exclusion principle?

Comment: Only for finite case also.

Comment: You can extend it for countably infinite by applying a trick. Observe that since $\mu$ is a measure it is continuous from below. So if $A_n\ \uparrow\ A$ then $\mu(A_n) \to \mu (A).$ Here in this case $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n} A_k\ \bigg\uparrow\ A,$ where $A = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n.$ So $$\mu (A) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \mu \left (\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n} A_{k} \right ).$$  Can you now finish?

Answer (score 1):

Define $B_{n}=\cup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}$. We can prove by induction that
$\mu(B_{n})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mu(A_{i})$. Observe that $B_{1}\subseteq B_{2}\subseteq\ldots$
and $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{i}=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_{i}$. By continuity
of measure,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu\left(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{i}\right) & = & \mu\left(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_{i}\right)\\
 & = & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(B_{n})\\
 & = & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mu(A_{i})\\
 & = & \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_{i}).
\end{eqnarray*}